# Google Analytucs v4 Android No campaign data found

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I works with google analytics v4 on android and i have troubles after install GAV4 service.

THis is my global_tracker.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-3</string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <screenName name="my.app.com">Screen 0 - Splash</screenName>
    ... 
</resources>
```

This file have more of "screenName" values, but i delete it for example.

In the "Application" class i have this code:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Analytics.init(this);
}
```

Line Analytics.init(this) initialize Tracker like this:

```
private static Tracker tracker;
public static void init(Application application) {
    GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(application);
    analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
    if(tracker == null) {
        tracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
}

public static void trackScreenView(String screenName) {
    tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
    tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
    tracker.setScreenName(screenName);
    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
}
```

And also in Manifest i have installed broadcast service and google play services:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
               android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But after this installation i have Debugger message about data not found on GAV4:

```
I/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
```

Any knows about this bug and can help me for it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the "No campaign data found" log message is not an error. I see that and my GA is working. Note, however, that it took GA a couple of days to start reporting after the first instance started reporting in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the apk file to you device.

   adb install filename.apk
2. Type the following adb command:

   ..\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n your.package.name/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=testSource"

Note that the command given in [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns) link has a V3 Receiver.

Check logcat. 
The Campaign Found message should be there. 
Make sure the app is not running when the referrer is being sent. The app should be launched only after it is done.